# Search AD for empty sAMAccountName & userPrincipalName

Tags: active-directory, ldap, query

I'm in the process of implementing a User privilege management solution and it needs to audit all users within our AD. It's currently falling over due to an account which has two blank attributes: sAMAccountName & userPrincipleName. I've tried finding this account using the following LDAP query:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!sAMAccountType=805306370)(sAMAccountName=""))
```

But unfortunately this query fails to find anything.

What would be the best method to find this account?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really expecting to find a user account with no samAccountName?  That should not occur, and the system will not allow a user account to have an empty samAccountName if you try to clear it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filter assumes that `sAMAccountName` has been set to a value of `""` (that is, an emptystring)

If the `sAMAccountName` attribute has not been set at all, your filter won't match it. Search for accounts where [the attribute is not set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198810.aspx) instead:

```
(!sAMAccountName=*)
```

You could also combine the 2 statements to look for both:

```
(|(!sAMAccountName=*)(sAMAccountName=""))
```

Comment: Null != Empty. Good answer.

Comment: @mathias R. Jessen, apologies for accepting the answer so late! Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @JLPH better late than never ;-) Glad this helped